# Изменение цвета выводимого текста в консоль

Tags: c++, консоль, color

На вход функции подаётся **двумерный массив int'ов** (выводится зелёным) и **одномерный массив** (он хранится в пользовательском типе `output_structure`) **координат верхних левых углов**, по которым нужно вывести красным цветом содержимое массива и все последующие эл-ы, которые образуют квадарт размером `size_of_square`.

Вот пример того как это должно работать:
Входной массив int'ов:

 1 0 1

 0 1 1

 0 1 1

size_of_square = 2

 Массив координат (сначала строки, потом столбцы):

 1 1

Вывод

 1 0 1

 0 **1 1**

 0 **1 1** (квадрат единичек размером 2 должен быть красным)

Ниже представлена моя функция, но она выводит красным только верхнюю часть любого квадрата, т.е. мой вывод выглядит так:

 1 0 1

 0 **1 1**

 0 1 1

```
void print_array(int** in_array, int array_size, output_structure obj, int size_of_square)
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | Green));
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != array_size; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != array_size; ++j) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k != obj._size;)
            {
                if (obj.array_of_ij[k] == i && obj.array_of_ij[k + 1] == j)
                {
                    temp = size_of_square*2;
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | Red));
                    break;
                }
                k += 2;
            }
            temp -= 2;
            std::cout << in_array[i][j]<<" ";
            if (temp <= 0) SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | Green));
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | LightGray));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. условие проходит **только для столобцов**, а не для строк, будет достаточно добавить проход по всем эл-ам строк от `[i текущего]` до `[i + (size_of_square - 1)]`.

Реализовать это можно так:

```
void print_array(int** in_array, int array_size, output_structure obj, int size_of_square)
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | Green));
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != array_size; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != array_size; ++j) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k != obj._size;)
            {
                for (int h = 0; h != size_of_square; ++h)
                {
                    if (obj.array_of_ij[k] + h == i && obj.array_of_ij[k + 1]== j)
                    {
                        temp = size_of_square;
                        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | Red));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                k += 2;
            }
            --temp;
            std::cout << in_array[i][j]<<" ";
            if (temp <= 0) SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | Green));
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)((Black << 4) | LightGray));
}
```